# Error when creating a new project in Mavensmate

Tags: mavensmate

Just installed, sublime and MavensMate and I am running Mavensmate from Linux, Fedora and I get this error when I try to open a new project

[MAVENSMATE]: response from mm: /bin/sh: /home/kova78/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/MavensMate/mm/mm: cannot execute binary file

This directory "/User/MavensMate/mm/mm", doesn't exist on my disk. What creates this?

Could you please advise?

Comment: Are you using ``su`` to start sublime text?

Comment: Hi, Yes I dud. But I have an assumption that this error message "bash: ./mm: cannot execute binary file
" comes when there is a platform compatibility issue. My Fedora20 is 32bit and I guess mm file is for 64 bit platform. Could this be? If yes, is there a 32 bits version? Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: From their guide ``http://mavensmate.com/Plugins/Sublime_Text/Installation`` Fedora doesn't seem to be official supported.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure a workspace:

Click `MavensMate` => `Settings` => `User`

Then assign a working directory to "mm_workspace"

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I think something else wrong here, that is what I get from the bash shell:    
 [kova78@norad ~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/MavensMate/mm]$ ./mm
bash: ./mm: cannot execute binary file
Any clue?

Comment: Ok a bit confused, your question says when you try and open a new project. Are you not in the application trying to create a project?

Comment: I am in the application sublime 3 but when I click on "Mavensmate/Project New Project", nothing happens. Then I press CTRL + ` and I get the error message in the little console that I posted first. For some reason it cannot execute the file called nm. I went out to the bash shall and the file does exist and it also have execute permission too. Any idea?